# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager' has been registered

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm on Asp .Net Core 5. When I try to seed the database I get the following error:

```
"No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser]' has been registered."
```

From What I've read in other posts and threads it seems this happens if I have a custom User and don't get the correct UserManager in program.cs but this isn't the case here. I'm really lost after hours of searching for this error...

My **Startup.cs** configure services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                //Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;

                //Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                //User settings
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                //Sign in settings
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }
```

**Startup.cs** Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**Program.cs** main function:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        try
        {
            var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();

            var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
            var userMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var roleMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var adminRole = new IdentityRole("Admin");

            if (!ctx.Roles.Any())
            {
                roleMgr.CreateAsync(adminRole).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            if (!ctx.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin"))
            {
                var adminUser = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    Email = "admin@admin.com",
                };
                userMgr.CreateAsync(adminUser, "Passw0rd!!").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                userMgr.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser.Id, adminRole.Name).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure that this will help but why not seed database in [`OnModelCreating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) (note that you need to provide all fields to prevent changes in subsequent migrations) ? Also scope is disposable and you should dispose it.

Comment: If you remove your startup seeding code, is `UserManager` able to be injected elsewhere without any issues?

Comment: `using var scope` or your scoped services will hang around. You could also move that startup code into an `IHostedService`. And you could use an `async Task Main(...)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to do the steps suggested in the comments I noticed that I was using both ASP Net Identity and ASP Net Core Identity... I fixed by going core all the way so there are no conflicts